# SpringBoot logging - extraneous hyphen at start of every log entry

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot, logback

I am trying to eliminate a leading hyphen from our console and file logs in SpringBoot 1.3.5.RELEASE with default logback config.

Logging pattern looks like:

```
logging:
  pattern:
    console: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %clr([${spring.application.name}]){red} %clr(%5p) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %X{req.requestId} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%rEx}'
```

The file log pattern is similar, without the color coding. Both output every line **after** the first with a leading hyphen, which is making our syslog - logstash - grok filtering trickier.  Example output:

```
2016-06-21 11:52:00.576 [my-app] INFO etc.. (application started)
-2016-06-21 11:52:00.583 [my-app] DEBUG etc..
-2016-06-21 11:52:00.583 [my-app] INFO etc..
```

I can't see anything in the docs mentioning this behaviour. Welcome any advice on how to eliminate it, if possible!

**Update**

Thanks to Edgar's answer below, it turns out this was caused by the following at the end of our logging pattern:

```
${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%rEx}
```

I replaced it with:

${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:%rEx}

et voila, the hyphen at the start of the following line disappears. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-configuration

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's hard to diagnose without your providing the full logging format. I'm seeing something similar in our code, and it seems to be related to including this in the format:

${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}

If you're using it, then the hyphen may be the one before the %w. I'm not sure what the intended purpose of this is. If I find it, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: ah, so simple - just removed the hyphen from `${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:%rEx}`. I hadn't included it as I didn't think it was relevant.. will update my question with the full logging pattern - thanks!

Comment: how can I apply filters to it?

Answer (score 21):

The problem is in this part of `logging.pattern.console`:

```
${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%rEx}
```

`:-` is Logback's default value delimiter and is what you should use in logback.xml. However, you're configuring things in `application.properties` where it's Spring Framework's default value delimiter (`:`) which should be used.

As you've used `:-`, you're saying use the value of `LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD` and, if it's not set, use `-%rEx` instead.

The correct syntax is:

```
${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:%rEx}
```

Comment: Document link is [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-custom-log-configuration), search 'you should use Spring Boot’s syntax'

Answer (score 0):

The suggested answers are actually slightly wrong, or at least are missing some details of what is happening.

If you replace `${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%rEx}` with `${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:%rEx}`, Spring will interpolate it into `%rEx` when it parses the property file (unless there happens to be a property `LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD` available at that time).

`LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD` is actually a System property provided by `LoggingSystem` and it's intended to be interpolated by Logback (which uses the ":-" syntax for default values).

You can fix the issue by defining a Spring property for the dollar character

```
dollar: $
```

Then replace `${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%rEx}` with:

`${dollar}{LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%rEx}`

thus bypassing Spring property interpolation. Then Logback will take care of interpolating the resulting pattern.